How this circuit works? inductor amplifier
The inductors are to catch electromagnetic interference and then they get amplified by resistors R3 and R1? C3 is to remove any DC contents? How does it works and why from the first place a dc signal will be presented? What is the function of C4? R5 is to have logic low at the output when no cable is attached to JP1?
How does the inductor value will affect the circuit?

(My schematics, based on the LOM-instruments Elektrosluch-DIY on GitHub)

I would also be aware of offsets because of bias current for the opamp. especially with C3 and C7 in place.

C3 and C7 are to remove DC content but there shouldn't be any. I would eliminate these two caps since they serve no purpose and are polarized for no good reason. The gain of each amplifier is 390 which is quite high. Any small internal DC offset will be amplified and appear on the output. C4 and C8 eliminate those DC offsets but should not be polarized caps. R5 and R8 present something of a ground-referenced impedance to the jack and will drain any ESD that might appear.
C3 and C7 can be removed. C4 and C8 should also be changed to non polarized ceramic capacitors. The signal going through them is AC and the polarity could be reversed. The value of C4 and C8 are chosen by the lowest frequency that should be passed along into the unknown output impedance after the jack. If that impedance is 1K then they should be chosen to have a reactance of a tenth of that or 100 ohms at that frequency for minimal loss. X = -j/(2pif*C).
The two feedback resistors across the top of the OP Amp cannot be reduced too much because there will be too much current being drawn from the output to the input. OP Amp output current is limited. Better to go with high value resistors. At 257 ohms, the current could be 4.5/257 or 17mA which is getting to be pretty high for a common Op Amp.

So I should remove C3 and C7 completely? what will be the difference between using 390k and 1k or using 100k and 257R ? both will give gain of 390. C4 and C8 can be lower value rather then 2.2uF?

It is common in audio circuits to use polarised capacitors. I see no reason to alter the circuit - it’s just a simple audio preamp with the inductors as pickups.

Well, as an RF Engineer, I would never subject a polarized cap to reverse voltage. The dielectric chemistry doesn't work properly.
